# Запредельное потребление ОЗУ в Firefox Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

Пишу парсер на Selenium.

В начале парсер проходит по страницам с проектами (20 штук на странице), сохраняем все это в список (около 2к ссылок).

Затем по очереди проходим по всем им и парсим 3 параметра и заносим в список словарей.

При этом Firefox потребляет немереное количество ОЗУ - около 8 Гбайт, хотя у Chrome все в порядке с этим.

Может кто подсказать, с чем это связано?

Прилагаю код:

```
all_develops = []    
def parse_list_develops(driver):
    urls_develop = []
    driver.get("https://www.hurriyetemlak.com/projeler/developers")
    print("Ожидание 6 секунд. Обход защиты")
    time.sleep(6)

    while True:
        time.sleep(2)

        #Ищем ссылки на проекты:
        a_list_develop = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.b-developer__logo-wrap > a")
        for a in a_list_develop:
            href = a.get_attribute("href")
            print("Ссылка на проект", href)
            urls_develop.append(href)

        #Блок пагинации
        try:
            pagination_block = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.b-pagination__item.b-pagination__item--next.js-pagination-next")))
            pagination_block.click()
            print("Перешли на следующую страницу")
        except Exception as e:
            try:
                print("Проверка наличия всплываюшего окна")
                button_close = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.b-button.b-button--full.b-button--confirm")
                time.sleep(2)
                button_close.click()
                time.sleep(2)
                print("Окно закрыли")
                pagination_block = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.b-pagination__item.b-pagination__item--next.js-pagination-next")))
                pagination_block.click()
                print("Нажатие на pagination снова")
            except Exception as e:
                print("Pagination не найдены. Конец перехода между страницами", e)
                break

    return urls_develop, driver    




def init_driver():
        ff = "../install/geckodriver.exe"


        try:
            driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=ff)
        except SessionNotCreatedException:
            print("Ошибка инициализации браузера. Скорее всего у вас не установлен браузер. Пожалуйста обратитесь к разработчику парсера")

        return driver

def pasring_develops(driver, urls_develop):
    # Блок парсинга проектов
    for url in urls_develop:
        print("Парсинг", url)
        driver.get(url)

        id_develop = get_index()

        name = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1.b-developer-combine-title__main-title"))).text.strip()
        name_rus = get_translated_text(name)

        try:
            god = int(
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.b-developer-statistic__item[data-test="Foundation"]').text.strip())
        except:
            god = None
        try:
            desckription_turkey = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
            'div.b-developer__description-container.js-developer__description-container > p').text.strip()
            desckription_rus = get_translated_text(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
            'div.b-developer__description-container.js-developer__description-container > p').text.strip())
        except:
            desckription_turkey = None
            desckription_rus = None

        logo_image = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.b-developer-logo > img').get_attribute('src')

        temp = []
        temp.append(["Id", id_develop])
        temp.append(["Name", name])
        temp.append(["Name RUS", name_rus])
        temp.append(["Year foundation", god])
        temp.append(["Image", logo_image])
        temp.append(["Description", desckription_turkey])
        temp.append(["Description RUS", desckription_rus])

        all_develops.append(dict(temp))
        print(id_develop, name, name_rus, logo_image, god, desckription_rus, desckription_turkey)



if __name__ == '__main__':
        start = time.time()
        driver = init_driver()
        urls, driver = parse_list_develops(driver)
        # print("Количество develop:", len(urls))
        print("Количество ссылок:", len(urls))

        print("Количество ссылок обновленных:",len(urls))
        driver = pasring_develops(driver, urls)
```

Проблема возникает именно тогда, когда мы начинаем переходить по ссылкам.
Каждая вновь открытая ссылка добавляем к потреблению около 10мб

Comment: Если мой ответ Вам помог, обозначьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый нажатием на `v` под счётчиком голосов

Answer (score 2):

Похоже, Firefox так увлечен выгрузкой страницы, что не останавливается и после возврата управления в скрипт из `driver.get(url)`.

Один из вариантов решения проблемы, вставить в код `pasring_develops` (поправьте опечатку в имени функции):

```
time.sleep(2)
```

Посмотрите, сколько ему стоит спать, чтобы он успевал разобраться с загруженным.

Альтернативный вариант - загрузить несколько драйверов сразу и использовать в цикле по-очереди. Пока один трудится, остальные разбираются со своими сборщиками мусора.